# Multiple forms, detect which one onclick came from

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

I have a webpage with multiple forms, each with it's own controls.

I want to use the "onclick" event on the controls to run a JavaScript function.

Is there some way to tell which **form** contained the **control** that the "onclick" event came from? 
I would like to do it without using the id of the form, but it's OK if I have to.

(I want to do a submit, on which ever the form it came from.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the form attributed to any input element by simply checking for it's `.form` like so:

For the element just set `onclick="getForm(this);"`

```
// el gets passed by "this" within the onclick
function getForm (el) {
    var form = el.form;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo - open console to see the "el" being passed in, as well as the parent form](http://jsfiddle.net/4SWtR/1/)

On a side note: I'd recommend **not** using **onclick / onmouseover / any "JS" events** within your HTML elements. Not only should these different things be separated in general, but in IE8 and lower, every single one of these events turns into a small *script* block element, which slows down performance.

Comment: You should tell him where `el` comes from if you're not going to pass it in the function ;)

Comment: Sorry, I am kind of new to this site. I don't see a green check mark. I clicked on the - Was this post useful to you?

Comment: To the left of my post is the arrows with (4) inbetween them, you should see the check mark below it